# Style Customization in a Hugo loveit theme

Tags: sass, hugo

I'm pretty new with Hugo, I want to edit the style of some elements generated by the markdown content ( table , text , Bash window ).
The loveit documentation provides this instruction:

> LoveIt theme has been built to be as configurable as possible by
> defining custom .scss style files. The directory including the custom
> .scss style files is assets/css relative to your project root
> directory.
>
> In assets/css/_override.scss, you can override the variables in
> themes/LoveIt/assets/css/_variables.scss to customize the style.

I tried to override some variables on the _override.scss file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be followed by [`dillonzq/LoveIt` issue 398](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt/issues/398)

> After checking again, I came to the conclusion that it works.

> When I copied variables form `_variables.scss`, I copied them with the `!default` keyword and it didn't worked.
> But if for `$global-background-color-dark: #292a2d !default;` I paste `$global-background-color-dark: #ff0000;` it works fine.

Note also that, in [issue 210](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt/issues/210#issuecomment-612445692) and [109](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt/issues/109), you would see the same `_override.scss` in `config/css/`, so that would be another path to test (in the root folder of your project).

In both instances (`assets/css/_override.scss` or `config/css/_override.scss`), we are talking about the root folder of your own project, not `themes/LoveIt/...`)